# Hyperledger Custom Chaincode deployment error

Tags: go, blockchain, hyperledger

I'm using Hyperledger to work on a POC. I've set the chaincode setup as mentioned [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/Setup/Chaincode-setup.md#chaincode-deploy-via-cli-and-rest) . I'm following the Option 1 mentioned in the link(using vagrant to run a CA server and one VP). In my current setup, I'm running with security disabled. My VP is running fine, and I'm able to start and register the chaincode just fine (as per mentioned [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/Setup/Chaincode-setup.md#starting-and-registering-the-chaincode). But, when I'm trying to deploy my chaincode via CLI with the following command :

```
peer chaincode deploy -n mycc -c '{"Function":"init", "Args": `["hi there"]}'`
```

I am getting the following error

```
Error: Error building chaincode: rpc error: code = 2 desc = "Error getting chaincode package bytes: Cannot generate hashcode from empty chaincode path"
```

I tried specifically mentioning the path where I've stored my custom chaincode, I get the following error :

```
Error: Error building chaincode: rpc error: code = 2 desc = "Path to chaincode does not exist: /opt/gopath/src/ProductBC/ProductBC/finished/"
```

Has anyone faced a similar issue or any points on what can be done to overcome this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like that you use full path to your chaincode  “/opt/gopath/src/ProductBC/ProductBC/finished/” but `peer` will try to find chaincode in you gopath by default.

Just try to run CLI command with “ProductBC/ProductBC/finished/“ instead.

```
peer chaincode deploy -p ProductBC/ProductBC/finished -c '{"Function":"init", "Args": `["hi there"]}'`
```

in this case peer will try to find this chaincode in $GOPATH/src/ProductBC/ProductBC/finished

P.S. Updated after discussion in chat.

Comment: so, my GOPATH is '/opt/gopath/' and my chaincode resides inside the '/src' directory. So, I tried with the following command :
" peer chaincode deploy -p /src/ProductBC/ProductBC/finished -n mycc -c '{"Function":"init", "Args": `["hi there"]}'` ", it doesn't throw any error now but seems to get stuck. Updated the question with the new status.

Comment: 'src' is not necessary. can you try to run this command without it ? (just updated the example in answer)

Comment: by restart the peer you mean building the peer again via 'make peer' or just restart the peer by 'peer node start' command ?

Comment: still the same issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117769/discussion-between-sergey-balashevich-and-tortuga).

Comment: I wondered why they used different path structures (relative/absolute) for golang and node chaincodes. Now I know, thank you for the insight.